# send input type=file to controller and save in database

Tags: ajax, postback, input-type-file

I want to upload the file without post back.
When I select the file and click on upload, I am not able to send the file data to controller.
As result of which the `Request.Files=null`.

Can anyone please tell me how can I send file data to controller using `ajax` call.

Answer (score 0):

You need to encrypt your post data in [multipart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) and deserialize on server side. 
I can recoment you FineUploader http://fineuploader.com/